# Can't su to jenkins even though login shell is /bin/bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu, jenkins, sudo

I can't seem to `su` to jenkins user even though the login shell is already set to `/bin/bash`. When I attempt to run `sudo su - jenkins -s /bin/bash`, the user does not switch and I see the same prompt.

I've rebooted the machine and restarted the service using `sudo systemctl restart jenkins`.

I made sure that the `jenkins` login shell is not `/bin/false` like [this question points out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/339672/167524). My `/etc/passwd` shows this for jenkins:

```
jenkins:x:121:129:Jenkins,,,:/var/lib/jenkins:/bin/bash
```

Jenkins does run when I reboot the machine, but the service fails to start when I try to restart it.

**Any idea why I can't su into jenkins?**

Thanks

Comment: try `sudo su - jenkins` only. it will ask password for logged in user.

Please share the error for jenkins restart. you can check the jenkins log file  for error

Comment: `sudo su - jenkins` unfortunately did not show any prompt for me. The error i got from restarting Jenkins was `Failed to start LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time.` with exit code 7. [Full log here](https://pastebin.com/pE4CtiYA).

Comment: Why jenkins tries to use `su` have you modified anything ?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** the below solution is not what fixed it for me. I'm still not sure what the root cause was, it may have been related to the Jenkins user not having read permission to some files, but I resolved it by reinstalling Jenkins.

<strike>It turns out that my `/etc/sudoers` file had:</strike>

```
jenkins   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

I changed it to:

```
jenkins ALL= NOPASSWD: ALL
```

and now I can switch to the `jenkins` user.

Comment: It seems this is not a complete solution, since the next boot I could not switch to Jenkins user again.